# Encountered a strange problem when writing b+trees using Python

Tags: python, default-parameters, b-plus-tree

Tree node structure:

```py
class BPlusNode:
    def __init__(self,isleaf = True,val=[],parent=None,children=[]):
        self.values = val
        self.children = children
        self.parent = parent
        self.isleaf = isleaf
        self.order=3
```

where the bug appears:

```py
def split(self,node):
    if (len(node.children)==0 and len(node.values) <= self.order) or (len(node.children)!=0  and len(node.values) < self.order):
        return
    if node.parent==None:
        #if current node is the root , create a new node as root
        new_root=BPlusNode(isleaf=False)  #something wrong this line

        global CNT
        CNT+=1 
        if(CNT>5):
            sys.exit()
        print('<debug>',new_root.values)

        node.parent=new_root
        self.root=new_root
        parent=new_root
```

input 3,1,4,5 in order
the output is:
[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkVH8.png)
strangely the new node has already been assigned values

but the program runs correctly if I write like this:

```py
new_root=BPlusNode(isleaf=False,val=[],parent=None,children=[])
```

Why does this happens?

I noticed a mechanism of default parameter in python:
operations on mutable objects with default parameters will be preserved
for example:

```py
cnt=2
def f(data=[]):
    global cnt
    data.append(1)
    print(data)
    data[0]=cnt
    cnt+=1
    return data
f()
f()
f()
```

the output will be:

```py
[1]
[2, 1]
[3, 1, 1]
```

but in my code:
`def __init__(self,isleaf = True,val=[],parent=None,children=[]):`
the parameter "val" has not been operated

Is this problem related to this mechanism?
Or it is caused by other reasons?

Comment: In the future, please make a [mcve] where the code produces the output you claim, and also put the output itself as text (not a link or image) in the question itself.

Comment: `val=[]` This assignment is performed only once, when the method is _defined_.  The assignment does NOT happen each time the method is _called_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, mutable default arguments are initialized when the function/method is *defined* so **every** `BPlusNode` that uses the mutable defaults receives the *same* list.

Instead use the following to avoid mutable defaults:

```py
class BPlusNode:
    def __init__(self,isleaf = True,val=None,parent=None,children=None):
        self.values = [] if val is None else val
        self.children = [] if children is None else children
        self.parent = parent
        self.isleaf = isleaf
        self.order3
```

This will assign a new empty list if the default is `None`, otherwise use the default.

It runs correctly here:

```
new_root=BPlusNode(isleaf=False,val=[],parent=None,children=[])
```

Because the default isn't used, and you explicitly pass in new list objects.